# Parent background only be visible from child element

Tags: html, css

I wanted to show the parent gradient just from child shape.

I tried adding `::after` to parent with white background to hide parent background color, but then child's background also becomes white.

Currently:

```css
#parent {
  background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
}

.top-10 {
  top: 10px;
}

.top-20 {
  top: 20px;
}

.top-40 {
  top: 40px;
}

.top-60 {
  top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child top-10"></div>
  <div class="child top-20"></div>
  <div class="child top-40"></div>
  <div class="child top-60"></div>
</div>
```

[image: current]

Expected:

[image: expected]

Also the child positions are changeable.

Comment: FYI StackOverflow supports runnable snippets (use the `<>` button) if your HTML/CSS is complete. This also allows people to easily copy your code to the answer to correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my solution:

```css
.child {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.top-10 {
  top: 10px;
}

.top-20 {
  top: 20px;
}

.top-40 {
  top: 40px;
}

.top-60 {
  top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child top-10"></div>
  <div class="child top-20"></div>
  <div class="child top-40"></div>
  <div class="child top-60"></div>
</div>
```

Another solution with background that is not changing on scroll:

```css
.child {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  outline: 10px solid white;
}

#parent {
  background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
  width: fit-content;
  height: 267px;
}

.child:before {
  content: '\fe3b';
  color: white;
  display: block;
  top: -60px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  font-size: 90px;
}

.child:after {
  content: '\fe3c';
  width: 60px;
  height: 10px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  font-size: 90px;
}

.top-10 {
  top: 10px;
}

.top-20 {
  top: 25px;
  /* correction here*/
}

.top-40 {
  top: 40px;
}

.top-60 {
  top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child top-10"></div>
  <div class="child top-20"></div>
  <div class="child top-40"></div>
  <div class="child top-60"></div>
</div>
```

Amir's solution:

```css
#parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
  background-size: 50px 300px;
}

.top-10 {
  top: 10px;
  background-position: 0px -20px;
}

.top-20 {
  top: 20px;
  background-position: 0px -70px;
}

.top-40 {
  top: 40px;
  background-position: 0px -140px;
}

.top-60 {
  top: 60px;
  background-position: 0px -2000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child top-10"></div>
  <div class="child top-20"></div>
  <div class="child top-40"></div>
  <div class="child top-60"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It could be great if background not be change on scrolling

Comment: I've added a new solution. Please, take a look.

Comment: Yeah, another workaround that I've found is, giving parent's height to child's `backgroud-size`, and give `background-position` to chidls relatively. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sucbfhwd/20/).

Comment: That was my very first attempt, but I didn't manage to make it work, I'm glad that for you it did.

Answer (score 0):

The parent element does not set other styles. The child element adds two important style attributes: **background: linear gradient (# e66465, # 9198e5);background-attachment: fixed;**. the gradient is used for four circles respectively.

all style codes:

```
.child {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  color: white;
}
.top-10 {
  top: 10px;
}
.top-20 {
  top: 20px;
}
.top-40 {
  top: 40px;
}
.top-60 {
  top: 60px;
}
```

be careful:
**background-attachment：fixed**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/css/background-attachment

Comment: Could you provide the code?